# Warning: Unknown block versions are being mined! Unknown rules may be active

Tags: bitcoin-core, asicboost

Best regards.
What's going on internally when I get this warning.

Warning: Unknown block versions are being mined! Unknown rules may be active

Bitcoin Core version v0.17.1 (64-bit)

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unusual Version Number in Blocks](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/79273/unusual-version-number-in-blocks)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This warning is currently benign and has been fixed for Bitcoin Core 0.18. You see it because miners are using the block version number for a mining optimization called ASICBOOST. However soft forks in the past have used the version number for readiness signalling. Bitcoin Core is seeing version numbers it is not expecting (due to ASICBOOST) and thus triggering the warning.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. You clarify the situation very well and give me peace of mind to continue contributing to the bitcoin network.