# What does the version number in the blockheader represent

Tags: block, hash

While looking up how a block get mined I stumbled over the version number in the header - which is used to "keep track of changes to the protocol".

But even in the last 5 blocks of the chain (at the state of writing) there were 4 different version numbers - so my questions are:

"What does the version number represent?" followed by "Will a mined block with a random version number get rejected - or could a miner simply use it as an extension of nounce (and thereby effectively double the length of the nounce)

Comment: Take a look at the answer provided here, it might help you out.
[Unusual Version Number in Blocks](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/79274/97740)

Comment: Also check out here [A Decomposition Of The Bitcoin Block Header](https://www.datadriveninvestor.com/2019/11/21/a-decomposition-of-the-bitcoin-block-header/)