# What are miners signalling for when the block header nversion field ends in 4 i.e. 0x3fffe004?

Tags: mining-pools, bip9-version-bits, asicboost

I've been researching into Overt (Version rolling) ASICBoost and tracking some of the latest mined blocks on https://asicboost.dance.

I've noticed that all recently mined blocks have the version ending in 4 i.e. by setting bit 2. I know that miners are signalling support for Segwit by setting bit 1. So, I'm not sure what they're signalling by setting bit 2?

I have been through many of the BIP documentations, but cannot seem to find any references for bit 2 being set. I've also reviewed a similar question already asked but the answer does not focus on bit 2. [Some miners set the nVersion field of the block header to 0x8000004. What were they signalling for? Was this an error?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96561/some-miners-set-the-nversion-field-of-the-block-header-to-0x8000004-what-were-t)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are signaling for Taproot. BIP 341 [specifies](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki#Deployment) that signaling occurs on bit 2.